# Is there any specific sql query to covert clob data to string?

Tags: database

One of the column is having clob data in DB and I want to validate whether a particular text is present in that clob data but i am not able to achieve it through sql query, as the formats differs . Is there any specific sql query to covert clob data to string?

Comment: Have you tried `CAST(your_clob_column AS VARCHAR)` or `CAST(your_clob_column AS VARCHAR2)`???

Comment: Yes, i tried but the result even after casting is same.